# Find next change in column

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a following dataframe

```
In[14]: data.head()
Out[14]: 
    2020-04-29 08:14:20.226546389+00:00    192800.0
    2020-04-29 08:14:20.316794250+00:00    192800.0
    2020-04-29 08:14:20.458210433+00:00    192810.0
    2020-04-29 08:14:20.506966171+00:00    192800.0
    2020-04-29 08:14:20.525237382+00:00    192800.0
```

What I would like to do is to add column 'next_move' which is 1 or -1 if the next price change is up or down. So in the first and second row I would like to get 1, then -1 etc...

I would like to omit the straight for loop with checking the next row that has the price different than in considered row. Do you have some ideas how to do it efficently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to get the first difference of the series, [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to account for the fact that we want the *next* row, and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to update with `1` or `-1` accordingly:

```
import numpy as np
df['next_move'] = np.where(df.col_2.diff().shift(-1 ,fill_value=0).ge(0), 1, -1)
```

Or we could also `map` the boolean series with a dictionary:

```
df['next_move'] = df.col_2.diff().shift(-1 ,fill_value=0).ge(0).map({False:-1,True:1})
```

---

```
print(df)
                               col_1     col_2  next_move
2020-04-29  08:14:20.226546389+00:00  192800.0          1
2020-04-29  08:14:20.316794250+00:00  192800.0          1
2020-04-29  08:14:20.458210433+00:00  192810.0         -1
2020-04-29  08:14:20.506966171+00:00  192800.0          1
2020-04-29  08:14:20.525237382+00:00  192800.0          1
```