# More effcient function to find next change in a dataframe column with time series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a large dataframe with a price column that stays at the same value as the time increases and then will change values, and then stay at that value new value for a while before going up or down. I want to write a function that looks at the price column and creates a new column called next movement that indicates wheather or not the next movement of the price column will be up or down.

For example if the price column looked like `[1,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,3,3,3,4,4,4,2,1]` then the next movement column should be `[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1]` with 1 representing the next movement being up 0 representing the next movement being down, and -1 representing unknown.

```
def make_next_movement_column(DataFrame, column):
    DataFrame["next movement"] = -1
    for i in range (DataFrame.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i + 1, DataFrame.shape[0]):
            if(DataFrame[column][j] > DataFrame[column][i]):
                DataFrame["next movement"][i:j] = 1
                break;
            if(DataFrame[column][j] < DataFrame[column][i]):
                DataFrame["next movement"][i:j] = 0
                break;
        i = j - 1
    return DataFrame
```

I wrote this function and it does work, but the problem is it is horribly ineffcient. I was wondering if there was a more effcient way to write this function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61498396/find-next-change-in-column) doesn't seem to work because the diff method only looks at the next column but I want to find the next movement no matter how far away it is.

Answer (score 0):

#### Annotated code

```
# Calculate the diff between rows
s = df['column'].diff(-1)

# Broadcast the last diff value per group
s = s.mask(s == 0).bfill()

# Select from [1, 0] depending upon the value of diff
df['next_movement'] = np.select([s <= -1, s >= 1], [1, 0], -1)
```

#### Result

```
    column  next_movement
0        1              1
1        1              1
2        1              1
3        2              1
4        2              1
5        2              1
6        4              0
7        4              0
8        4              0
9        3              1
10       3              1
11       3              1
12       4              0
13       4              0
14       4              0
15       2              0
16       1             -1
```